# How to remove white spaces around img tag?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't understand, why I should use `display: flex;` to get the image stretched for the whole space. Even if I set height of the `img` tag and for its parent (`.hey`) to `100%`, it won't work and would have white space.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .hey {
            /* If we won't place display: flex; the image height won't be affected and white space would occur */
            /* display: flex; */
            height: 100%;
        }

        .dance {
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .wrapper {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hey"><img src="./img/blog/blog2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="dance">
            <h4>Hey</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente rerum aliquid tempora ipsum facere
                neque, sint expedita nihil laboriosam accusantium.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you please explain why it works that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set a `display : block` on the `img` like so :

```css
 img {
      display:block;
      /* 
         the lines below is for when you want the image 
         fills its parent also vertically 
         whiteout loosing quality
      */
      height: 100%;
      object-fit:cover;
 }
```

Your attempt is not working because by default, an `img` is an `inline` element, which means `width` and `height` set via `CSS` won't have any effect . Having a `display : flex` on the parent makes it a `flex element`, which behaves to a certain point like a `block` element.

Answer (score 0):

img is an inline element. That means you cannot set its width or height. To do that you first need to make it a block or inline-block element, or you could just use display flex and img will now be flex-items. White space is due to margin of p tag

```
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

As suggested in a previous answer, you could use this code but it still wont work as you still need to make room for your p tag. You need to first think what you actually want. If you want your p tag to be placed on img then search on this site and there our tons of questions for you. If you want to align them left to right, then use

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
```

in both p and img tag. display: flex; is awesome too.